# How to get 3 items <li> in n items (css,jquery)

Tags: jquery, css

i want get 3 items in tag

ex:

```html
<ul>
  <li>div 1</li>
  <li>div 2</li>
  <li>div 3</li>
  <li>div 4</li>
  <li>div 5</li>
  <li>div 6</li>
  
</ul>
```

i want get 3 items, start at index[0] into index[2]. how can i do? with css or jquery?

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It really only takes a couple of hours, and it pays you that time back very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use [the `:lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) as a filter:

```
var firstThree = $("selector-for-the-ul").children(":lt(3)");
```

or [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
var firstThree = $("selector-for-the-ul").children().slice(0, 3);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("ul").children(":lt(3)").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("ul").children().slice(0, 3).css("color", "blue");
  }, 300);
}, 300);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>div 1</li>
  <li>div 2</li>
  <li>div 3</li>
  <li>div 4</li>
  <li>div 5</li>
  <li>div 6</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```
function sliceIt(start , end){
  $("li").slice(start,end).css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

now you can call a function

```
sliceIt(0,2); //0,1
sliceIt(3,6); //4,5,6
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/decpapt9/1/)

upon your need

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = true;
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        if(x == true){
            sliceIt(0 , 3);
            x = false;            
        }else{
            sliceIt(3 ,6);
            x = true;
        }
    });
});

function sliceIt(start , end){
      $("ul > li").css("background", "none");
      $("li").slice(start,end).css("background", "yellow");
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/decpapt9/2/)

Comment: now i want get array[3-6] next to array[0-2]? (3 elenments)

Comment: hi, sorry i know that, but i don't want use slice(3,6) .i want get it in loop

Comment: @HuỳnhTú in loop to do what? what you trying to do?

Comment: when i click button next, it will hide 3 elements at start (ex:[0]->[3]) and show 3 items next.when i click prev button, it will back to  3 items previous. . sorry i beginning learn jquery.

Comment: @HuỳnhTú updated answer .. you can learn about jquery from youtube tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810

Answer (score 0):

With css

```css
ul li:nth-child(-n+3){
  color:red;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>div 1</li>
  <li>div 2</li>
  <li>div 3</li>
  <li>div 4</li>
  <li>div 5</li>
  <li>div 6</li>
  
</ul>
```